# ReactJS how to run an API call when a state has a particular value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm teaching myself React and one of my exercises is using `axios` to fetch a list of countries from an API

```
const fetchCountries = () => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(fetchCountries, []);
```

Then as a user types into an input the list of countries filters down.

```
  const handleInputChange = event => {

    const filter = event.target.value; // current input value
    let matchingCountries = query !== ''
        ? countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        : countries;
    setQuery(filter);
    setMatches(matchingCountries)
    console.log('matches', matches)
    console.log('query', query)
  };
```

My *goal* is that when a single country is matched, a new API request is triggered (to fetch the weather, but the *what* isn't my problem, the timing is). When a single country is matched, I will then render some data about the country, then fetch and render the weather details for the single country's capital city.

One of the problems I'm having is that when I set the state, the value always seems to be one step behind. For example, in this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/helgatheviking/pen/gOOmMwW) when you enter FRA you should get "France". However, I have to enter "FRAN" to get the match. This doesn't happen when I don't use a state variable for the matches (just `let matches`). This becomes a problem because I need to run the next API call when the number of matches = 1, but the length of the matches state is always wrong.

So I would like to know 1. how to get the correct state of the matched countries. And 2. *when* I should run the second API call without getting into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is you are using an old `query` value in `handleInputChange()`.

Remember [setting the state is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) (i.e. doesn't take effect immediately)

Here's an updated version:

```
const handleInputChange = event => {

  const filter = event.target.value; // current input value
  let matchingCountries = filter ? <code here>
  // ...
  setQuery(filter);
};
```

**UPDATE**:

To call the weather api if there's a single country match is to have `matches` as dependency in `useEffect()`.

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    async function queryWeatherApi() {
      // const data = await fetch(...)
      // setData(data)
    }

    if (matches.length === 1) {
      queryWeatherApi();
    }
  },
  [matches]
)
```

Comment: Yes! Ok, that gets the matching happening. I think I'm getting the countries once (now), but next I'm trying to get the Weather once I find a single country match. When would I fire a new `.get()`? Yesterday I was in an infinite loop and blitzed the weather api. whoops.

Comment: @helgatheviking updated answer adding another effect to check for `matches.length`

Comment: If i simplify my input this _does_ get the weather API call to fire (and not fire infinitely like before). That leaves me with some questions about other things, but I think this solves the question as posted. Thanks Joseph!

Comment: Will the component re-render when `setWeather()` changes the weather state?

Comment: @helgatheviking yes for it's a state. i.e. `const [weather, setWeather] = React.useState({})`. glad to be of help!

Answer (score 2):

#### `useEffect` solution using separation of concern

**1 function should do 1 thing**

- `handleInputChange` updates state
- `useEffect` updates state

But they are not coupled. 
Later you might have a new function called `handleDropdownChange` which updates state
It that case you don't need to modify useEffect

<sup>At the end of the day, we (developers) don't like to rewrite things</sup>

```
  const [countries, setCountries] = React.useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = React.useState("");
  const [matches, setMatches] = React.useState([]);

  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let matchingCountries = query !== ''
        ? countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        : countries;
    
    setMatches(matchingCountries)
  }, [query]);                          // called whenever state.query updated
  
  const handleInputChange = event => {
    setQuery(event.target.value);       // update state
  };

  const fetchCountries = () => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then(response => {
      setCountries(response.data);
    });
  };

  React.useEffect(fetchCountries, []);
```

And there is also solution (not recommended) by directly using `event.target.value` provided by @Joseph D.

Comment: Thanks, Medet! What is the advantage of separating out `setMatches()` into another effect versus combining it with `handleInputChange()`?

Comment: @helgatheviking its separation of concern, **1 function should do 1 thing**, `handleInputChange` updates state, `useEffect` updates state, but they are not coupled. Later you might have a new function called `handleDropdownChange` which updates state, it that case you don't need to modify `useEffect`

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

1) The reason for your problem is in this line:

```
let matchingCountries = filter !== ''
        ? countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        : countries;
```

you use `query` instead of `filter` variable, your handler function should look like this:

```
const handleInputChange = event => {

    const filter = event.target.value; // current input value
    let matchingCountries = filter !== ''
        ? countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
        : countries;

    setQuery(filter);
    setMatches(matchingCountries)
  };
```

2) Where to run your next API call:
For studying purpose I do not want to recommend you using some application state management lib like `redux`.Just calling it right after `setFilter` and `setQuery`. It will run as expected. Because calling an API is asynchronous too so it will be executed after `setQuery` and `setFilter` what does not happen with `console.log`, a synchronous function.